# Double the current capability of a mains socket by wiring another in parallel

Tags: current, mains, parallel

I have an appliance that I know draws more or less 16A under 240VAC, but I only have 13A sockets around.

Is there any off the shelf solution?

Comment: You'll have to change the socket. What plug does the device have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diodes are used when linking DC supplies, not AC!

It sounds to me like you need something like this: [Ceenorm Link](http://cpc.farnell.com/1/1/194781-socket-panel-240v-16a-2pe-connector-mounting-panel-current-rating-16a-gender-receptacle-series-contact-termination-screw-msl-voltage-rating-240v-1311-ceenorm.html)

In the UK, you may have a ring-main, which actually gives you double the current rating on the sockets already, but you may need to change the MCB´s for the circuit. In any case, if you have any doubts, call an electrician! Mains can kill.

Comment: This is the correct answer - if it's a 16A device it should already have a suitable plug, and the ring main should be good for 24A at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). Of course, I just realised the stupidity of using diodes a bit late. Generally speaking, isn't there a way to put AC supplies in parallel?

Comment: You'll probably find it's a legal (part P) no-no to draw more than 13A from a socket on a ring main even if the ring is rated/fused at 32A. What you want really is a separate spur from the main fusebox that's fused appropriately to the cable and THEN terminated in either 16A or 32A blue commando socket which is the correct thing for larger mains currents.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. Don't do it. We're talking about mains power here! Hire an electrician to do it.

Longer answer. I would hire an electrician to change the fuses of that power outlet so that it tolerates 16A. By hiring an electrician you will save your life (and possible other due to the risks with malfunctioning mains power). An electrician will also tell you if you need other wiring and perhaps other electrical outlets.

Comment: I'm not sure changing the rating of the fuses is allowed. Also, I am not reckless. Whichever solution will be properly investigated before I do anything, I am well aware of the risks related to mains voltage. However, I do need to merge two 13A sockets, therefore this doesn't answer my question...